# AWS loadbalancer behaves strangely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am running 4 production servers behind a load balancer, 2 large on 1a and 2 large on 1b on Singapore region. I have disabled STICKY SESSION for it. My problem is: load balancer distributes more traffic to 1b region, which makes these instances to be run with 100% CPU and the 1a region instances to be free CPU. It is causing a lot of problems on website. How to get rid of this?

Comment: Do your client requests come from a common network? I have experienced this issue in the past when I sent a lot of requests through a common gateway (e.g. my clients were different machines on the same corporate network).

Comment: Viccari , no , its a production server ,users hitting the website from different locations .

Comment: I suggest going ahead and contacting AWS forums and/or support. Having your ELB and instances IDs, they are usually able to trace your issue.